# Summoning Awakened Monsters

Tags: summoners-war

Is it possible to summon a 4-5 star monster in it's awakened form? I know it happens with 2-3 stars. If so are there specific monsters that can?

Comment: Yeah I mean it's possible, but you could play for years and never see it. It's incredibly rare for this to happen.

Comment: It's only possible up to Nat4* monsters. Since they're all one level higher when summoned awakened and it's not possible to summon a 6*, you can not summon awaked Nat5*.

Comment: Yeah. I just summoned a 4 star awakened fire vagabond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but it is pretty rare to do it. See this sample video from YouTube at about the 2:40 mark.